# How to always check a condition in Android?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-studio, silent

I want to develop an app to toggle the device's audio status. If the audio status is silent then my button's text should be "silent", if it's normal the text should be "normal"

Here is my only class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
    {
        btn1.setText("Normal");
    }
    else if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
    {
        btn1.setText("Silent");
    }

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
                    {
                        audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                        btn1.setText("Silent");
                    }
                    else if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
                    {
                        audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                        btn1.setText("Normal");
                    }
                                      }
            });
        }
    });
```

How can I always check this condition in Android ?

Comment: What's the problem you are having? It seems like this should work fine.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry
my problem is that if user change audio the text of button does not change until the button pressed , i want to button text change immediately

Comment: Oh I see your problem.

Comment: Why nested `onClickListener`?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i change it with your guidance but i want to text of button always update and show audio status of phone

Comment: @Hossein: Please try my answer. This code would go inside `onCreate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the mode of current ringer even if it was changed outside from you application context then you should register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION`.

This receiver will be called everytime someone changes the ringer mode.

Do this inside `onCreate`.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
          {
              btn1.setText("Silent");
          }
          else if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
          {
              btn1.setText("Normal");
          }
    }
};

IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
        {
            audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            btn1.setText("Silent");
        }
        else if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
        {
            audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            btn1.setText("Normal");
        }
    }
});
```

what your are doing is

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
                {
                    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    btn1.setText("Silent");
                }
                else if (audio.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
                {
                    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    btn1.setText("Normal");
                }
             }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: pls explain that to me

Comment: You have nested `onClickListener`, remove that nesting.

Comment: its ok but my Question is another thing
i want to check silent/normal always in my app and with change to this status , change text of button automatically...
@Rohit5k2

Comment: in app or in this current activity?

Comment: i want to text of button always update and show audio status of phone....

@Usman

Comment: try to use broadcast receiver.might be it will work for you